# Nothing happens when I double click on android.bat

Tags: android, sdk

I have downloaded only the sdk tools `sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip` from the website : https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.

I want to run SDK manager but Nothing happens when I run the `android.bat` in `/tools`

Comment: Whenever I have a problem like this the first thing I do is open command prompt `cmd.exe`, navigate to where the `.bat` file is located and run it from command prompt. That way I can see the error message it produces when it tries to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a deprecated feature: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235625

You can access the SDK Manager from within Android Studio.